# Android Database Content

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-play

I am writing an application which will have around 5 tables and records up to 5k.
Which is the best way to create the database when someone installs the application from the Market ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those entries are static, you might want to save them in a sql script which is executed on the first start of the app.

If those entries might change from time to time, you might consider only saving the database structure and load the entries from the internet on the first start.

Comment: Then just add all of them in one single sql script, which is delivered with your application and run on the first startup.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db